# UILabel number of lines affecting the bounds size

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am having this peculiar behavior with `UILabel`. Any `numberOfLines` works ok, except 1. If I set the number of lines to 1 it ignores the width which I set later.
I don't understand why 1 line screws it up...

here is my code

> ```
> UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
> label.text = @"here is my label with lots of text to fill, here is my label with lots of text to fill";
> label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 0);
> CGRect rect = label.frame;
> label.numberOfLines = 2;
> label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
> [self.view addSubview:label];
> rect.size.width = 100;
> label.frame = rect;
> [label sizeToFit];
> ```

Comment: Sorry, probably I expressed myself unclearly. I want to be able to change the number of lines, but keep fixed width of the label regardless of how much text there is.

Comment: Please see my answer for it.My answer will work proper..

Comment: You mean you wanna see your result in only one line..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.text = @"here is my label with lots of text to fill, here is my label with lots of text to fill";
label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 0);
label.numberOfLines = 3;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
[self.view addSubview:label];

[label sizeToFit];

CGRect rect = label.frame;
rect.size.width = 100;
label.frame = rect;
```

With `numberOfLines = 3`:

[image: image1]

With `numberOfLines = 1`:

[image: image2]

Comment: Yes, I do need this, but I also need to be able to set it to other amount of lines, e.g. 3..

Comment: @AuRis take a look at it now.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant! For some reason I thought I tried it and it didn't work. I was wrong.

Comment: No problem Au Ris, I'm glad that helped you!

Comment: After so many days I noticed this solution doesn't work on older versions... in particular 5.1. Any ideas why that would be the case?

Comment: this doesn't work when the text is small and still you are using the complete width (100).. beats the purpose of sizeToFit

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use numberOfLines = 1 in that case your text will be in one line.So please use `numberOfLines = 0`;

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

And there is no need to again define label frame so  please remove these statement.

```
CGRect rect = label.frame;
rect.size.width = 100;
label.frame = rect;
```

Use this code this is perfect..

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.text = @"here is my label with lots of text to fill, here is my label with lots of text to fill";
label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 0);
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
[self.view addSubview:label];

[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to set to a desired number of lines. Your suggestion only fits to the whole text.

Comment: According to you this text will be static.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it doesn't work when numberOfLines=1

I have to add this line at the end to make it work for all cases..

label.width = min(label.width, 100)

Answer (score -1):

Use this as :

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.text = @"here is my label with lots of text to fill, here is my label with lots of text to fill";

label.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100 , 9999) lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
float lHeight = labelSize.height;
label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, lHeight);

label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

EDIT :  `- (void)sizeToFit`

**Description :**

Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.
Call this method when you want to resize the current view so that it uses the most appropriate amount of space. Specific UIKit views resize themselves according to their own internal needs. In some cases, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

```
// [label sizeToFit];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this does exactly the same what my code does. Try setting to 1 line and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ya right. I saw this. I am check this issue and let you know soon.

Comment: I got the issue. You are using [label sizeToFit]; that why its size is extending according to the text.. So remove this line. Check my edited answer

Comment: I use [label sizeToFit] because i need to fit the label to the size of the text :)